# How can I get an alert with layers count before they change?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript, cc-2019

I have this function below and before it calls `bevel();` function, I want first to add an `alert` where it says how many layers going to be change...

```
function goThroughLayers(parentLayer){
    for(var i=0; i<parentLayer.layers.length; i++){
        curLayer = parentLayer.layers[i];
        doc.activeLayer = curLayer;         
        if(curLayer.typename == 'LayerSet'){
            goThroughLayers (curLayer)
        }else{
            if(curLayer.parent.name == 'Group 2' && curLayer.name == 'Rectangle 1' && curLayer.kind == LayerKind.SOLIDFILL){                  
                bevel ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Then you would need to loop 2 times. To collect the actual matching layers

Comment: you can make a temp array like var temp = [] and then you can add one command temp.push(curLayer) and in your alert you can pass alert(temp.length)

Comment: Can I have an example based on my code please? I am new to Photoshop scripting and not any ace in javascript so... Thank you both!!!

Comment: it will be fine if you can share full code and situation so we can reproduce because this current one doesn't helping me to understand clearly!

Comment: I made it!!! I did what you both said... I'll "spruce up" my code and I'll add it here if someone else need it...

Comment: by running your code i figured that if and only if your layer name is Rectangle 1 shape layer inside of Group 2 then it should get Bevel effect now where especially and why you want to get count of layer>]

Comment: @DesignPhoenix those values are just for test... I'll add prompt windows before all this happens and will be able to type what user wants!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I made two loops. One for count the layers that are going to change and one that adds an effect to specific layers as **joojaa** said. I also used `push()` method as **Design Phoenix** said. Here is my code...

```
function main(){

    var doc = activeDocument;
    var count = [];
    var curLayerA;   
    var curLayerB;

    goThroughLayersA(doc);   

    if (confirm('You are about to add selected effect on ' + count.length + ' layers. Do you want to continue?', false, 'Message')) {
        goThroughLayersB(doc); 
    }
    else {
        return;
    }

    function goThroughLayersA(parentLayer){
        for(var i = 0; i < parentLayer.layers.length; i++){
            curLayerA = parentLayer.layers[i];
            doc.activeLayer = curLayerA;         
            if(curLayerA.typename == 'LayerSet'){
                goThroughLayersA (curLayerA)
            }else{
                if(curLayerA.parent.name == 'Group 2' && curLayerA.name == 'Rectangle 1' && curLayerA.kind == LayerKind.SOLIDFILL){
                    count.push(curLayerA);
                }
            }
        }
    }   

    function goThroughLayersB(parentLayer){
        for(var i = 0; i < parentLayer.layers.length; i++){
            curLayerB = parentLayer.layers[i];
            doc.activeLayer = curLayerB;         
            if(curLayerB.typename == 'LayerSet'){
                goThroughLayersB (curLayerB)
            }else{
                if(curLayerB.parent.name == 'Group 2' && curLayerB.name == 'Rectangle 1' && curLayerB.kind == LayerKind.SOLIDFILL){
                    bevel();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function bevel(){
        // Code for bevel and emboss effect here!!!
    } 

}
main();
```

If you believe that the code is okay and nothing better can be done, please let me know so to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: You should probably code this so that `goThroughLayers` accepts a function instead of repeating everything.

Comment: @joojaa can you give me an example?

Comment: Something like [this](https://pastebin.com/JTRfXbaH)

Comment: I tested your code and it works only if I uncomment `doc.activeLayer = curLayer;`!!!

Comment: That sounds weird. Works fine for me without it.

Comment: Try to create three shapes by the name "Rectangle 1" into a group by the name "Group 2" and run the script. It changes only one of them. Then if you uncomment `doc.activeLayer = curLayer;` you'll notice that changes all.